# MySQL Select with Offset is Faster Than no Offset

Tags: mysql, performance, inner-join, limit, offset

I've been messing around with query performance for a system with pagination to make the data selection as fast as possible, but I've come across something I don't quite understand. To my knowledge, when a limit with an offset is used, MySQL has to iterate through each row before the offset and then discard them, so in theory a query with an offset of 10,000 would be much slower than one without, which is normally true as in this case

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE * from `customers` where `NetworkID`='\func uuid()' 
    order by `DateTimeAdded` desc limit 0, 100;
/* finishes in 2.497 seconds */

 select SQL_NO_CACHE * from `customers` where `NetworkID`='\func uuid()' 
   order by `DateTimeAdded` desc limit 10000, 100;
 /* finishes in 2.702 seconds */
```

But, if I use an inner join to join the table to itself with only `UserID` column for doing the sorting and limiting, it's consistently *faster* with the offset of 10,000 than without one, which completely stumps me. Example here would be

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE * from `customers` 
    inner join (select `UserID` from `customers` where `NetworkID`='\func uuid()' 
        order by `DateTimeAdded` desc limit 100) 
    as `Results` using(`UserID`)
/* finishes in 1.133 seconds */

select SQL_NO_CACHE * from `customers` 
    inner join (select `UserID` from `customers` where `NetworkID`='\func uuid()' 
        order by `DateTimeAdded` desc limit 10000, 100) 
    as `Results` using(`UserID`)
/* finishes in 1.120 seconds */
```

Why is the query using the offset always faster than the query without the offset?

---

Explains:

I have posted a Google Docs spreadsheet here with the `explains` content [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cEaeREV4uO_hSm668CAUChm6Oo_SWIvuLRkmyOkoghw/edit?usp=sharing)

<sub>Note: The tests above were done in PHP looping 20 times each</sub>

<sup>Note<sup>2</sup>: `customers` is a view, not a base table</sup>

Comment: try different offsets, see if u get same trend. might be this specific offset has a very simple join

Comment: I have, if I do this with 30,000 even, it's still consistently faster than the query without the offset

Comment: `optimize` the table and see if it is the same (neutrlize all unknown factors first)

Comment: @Brian Leishman : I wonder whether you always run those 2 queries the same order for tests.

Comment: Also thought of that @a1ex07, if I switch the order of the queries, the one with the offset still wins

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka, it might be worth noting that this is actually a view that I'm using, and not a base table

Comment: Can you post result of `explain` for the queries ?  Even though the difference is tiny (1.13 vs 1.12 which is roughly 1%)  the second one should be slower unless fetch time is the culprit here, not execution time.

Comment: @a1ex07 I've added a link at bottom to the data from both of the explains

Comment: @BrianLeishman : Then  I'd suggest profiling both queries (there is an example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27042246/mysql-workbench-how-come-the-duration-time-fetch-time-real-waiting-time    )

Comment: Please also post explains for queries without the join. I am courious about access path MySql has chosen in these queries. It might be also helpful if you showed us a query hidden under `customers` view.

Comment: @kordirko I've added the explains for the other queries to the bottom of the Google Sheet

Comment: What's the "\func" about?

Comment: The subquery "trick" really shines if the table is too big to be cached.  I suspect all the OP's tests had all the data fully cached in the buffer_pool.  The timing diff is due to the size of the intermediate table (all columns vs just the id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1:  The optimizer can use an index on the `ORDER BY`.  `LIMIT 10` will be faster than `LIMIT 10000,10` because it can stop reading rows sooner.

Case 2:  The optimizer cannot (or chooses not to) use an index for the `ORDER BY`.  In this case, the entire set of rows (after `WHERE`) is collected, that set is sorted, and only then the `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` are applied.  In this case the value of `OFFSET` makes little difference; most of the time was consumed fetching rows, filtering them, and sorting them.

```
INDEX(x,y)
SELECT ... WHERE x=2               ORDER BY y LIMIT ... -- case 1
SELECT ... WHERE x=2 AND deleted=0 ORDER BY y LIMIT ... -- case 2

INDEX(NetworkID, DateTimeAdded)         -- composite
SELECT ... WHERE NetworkID='...' ORDER BY DateTimeAdded DESC ... -- Case 1

INDEX(NetworkID), INDEX(DateTimeAdded)  -- separate
SELECT ... WHERE NetworkID='...' ORDER BY DateTimeAdded DESC ... -- Case 3
```

Case 3 might be like Case 1 because it *might* use `INDEX(DateTimeAdded)`.  Or, of the optimizer chooses to use the other index, then it is a slow Case 2.  Anyway, it is not as good as using the composite index that can handle both the `WHERE` and the `ORDER BY`.

If you can manage to get to Case 1, I recommend you also "remember where you left off" to make Pagination even more efficient.  See [my Pagination blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

[More on creating INDEXes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Comment: Yes, I've read a ton about pagination and I've come across the strategies of "remembering where I left off", but none of which would really help me in my situation. Reason 1 being that this always requires that I have numerical data which I simply can't use because I have multiple servers that merge. Reason 2, is that I show a filtered subset of the data, that can be ordered by the user in any way, which means that the data is *never* in numerical order.

Comment: Have I at least explained why the `OFFSET` does not impact the speed?  (Namely, that most of the time happened _before_ applying the `OFFSET`.)

Comment: Yes, I do believe you have though explained why my queries seem odd, and thank you for that!